# Emacs - Can't map C-[

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings

I'm trying to map <kbd>C-[</kbd> in Emacs to do the same as <kbd>C-g</kbd>. I tried this:

```
(global-set-key "\C-[" 'keyboard-escape-quit)
```

But Emacs behaves strangely after remapping <kbd>C-[</kbd>. For example, <kbd>M-x</kbd> stops working and if I try to remap <kbd>M-x</kbd> I get the following error:

> error: Key sequence M-x starts with non-prefix key ESC

Why does this happen? Is there a workaround?

Comment: `Ctrl-[` is `Escape`, at least in some terminals.

Comment: I'm using the emacs gui, so it shouldn't matter, should it? Also, emacs already overrides some terminal commands, like Ctrl h...

Comment: There are minimum 3 keystrokes for `M-` keybindings: `ESC`, `C-[`, `Alt`. They use common keymap: `M-x` and others are defined in it. This is created for convenience: for keyboards without `Alt` or limited terminals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C-[` is the same as `ESC`, the Escape key.  You probably do not want to rebind `ESC`, since it is used in many, many, many keybindings, as a prefix key.  It implements the Meta key modifier in many cases, which is probably why you say that "Emacs behaves strangely" after you rebound it (removing its prefix-key behavior).  See the Emacs manual, node `User Input`.

As to "Is there a workaround?" -- pick another key (leave `ESC` alone).

And wrt `ESC` and `C-g`: See the Emacs manual, node `Quitting` (also node `Menu Bar`).

Comment: That's strange because `(global-set-key [escape] 'keyboard-escape-quit)` works fine. I'll wait to see if someone comes up with an solution, if not, I'll accept yours. Thanks

Comment: It's not a great idea, IMHO. Emacs and Emacs libraries generally expect `ESC` to behave as it does, at multiple levels. You are free to  tweak things as you like, but I wouldn't recommend fiddling with `ESC`.  IOW, IMO, not a solution because not a real problem (just one opinion).  Put differently, **what is the real problem?**  Sounds like this is perhaps an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821).  Remapping `ESC` sounds like an attempt at a solution, but what is the problem that led to that attempt?